# Get Return Type on prisma generic function

Tags: node.js, typescript, backend, typescript-generics, prisma

Im building a database Service based upon prisma client Extensions.
Ive managed to build some funcctions that allow me to access all models but im unable to return the typed response of the function.
so up to now im returning a unknown response and infering the types on the fly.

Can anyone Help me ?

This is the code

```
import { PrismaClient, type Prisma } from '@prisma/client'
import { logger } from './logger.service'
import { type IResponseObject, ResponseObject, type GenericResponseObject } from '../Entities'
export abstract class DatabaseHandler {
      static Instance: any
      constructor (
        protected unExtendedPrisma = new PrismaClient(),
    
        protected prisma = unExtendedPrisma.$extends({
    
          model: {
    
            $allModels:
            {
              async  gCreate <T>(
                this: T & { create: (...args: any) => any },
                args: Prisma.Args<T, 'create'>['data']
              ): Promise<GenericResponseObject<unknown>> {
                try {
                  const data = await this.create({ data: args })
                  logger.debug({
                    function: 'DatabaseHandler.create', data
                  })
                  return new ResponseObject(null, true, data)
                } catch (error) {
                  logger.error({ function: 'DatabaseHandler.create', error })
                  return new ResponseObject(error, false, null)
                }
              }              
        )
      ) {
        if (DatabaseHandler.Instance !== undefined) return DatabaseHandler.Instance
        DatabaseHandler.Instance = this
        return DatabaseHandler.Instance
      }
    }
```

Im actually should be extending T type on the generic declaration to extend any given prisma model but im unable to do that.
even thougth in a generic utility type to do a deep dive of T but im not good enough to do that.
any directions you can provide me would be apreciated

Comment: Please add usage example with `unknown` comment

Comment: Sorry but i dont seem to understand your comment. 
What im implementing rigth now since i dont seem to find i way to get the actual return type of the method is returning an unknown type and then norrowing it on the controller instance.